# How to parse Audiences from list item

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, target-audience

I have a `SPList` which is audience aware and I need to parse it's audiences from a `SPListItem`.

```
string Audiences;

public Class1(SPListItem item)
{
  this.Audiences = item[FieldId.AudienceTargeting] as string;
}
```

I've come to this so far. I've been searching how to parse each audience from the item but I couldn't find much help.

Does someone know to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper way to retrieve Audience Targeting contents from the List is to do the following.

```
string audString = item[fieldId.AudienceTargeting] as string;
string[] audienceIds;
string[] distinguishedNames;
string[] spGroups;
AudienceManager manager = new AudienceManager();
AudienceManager.GetAudienceIDsFromText(audienceAsText, out audienceIds, out distinguishedNames, out spGroups);
var namesList = manager.GetAudienceNames(new ArrayList(globalAudienceID.Select(id => new Guid(id)).ToList()));
```

This way if the format of the string changes, the change in api in GetAudiencEIDsFromText will evolve accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

from [this artical](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syedi/archive/2008/09/12/enabling-the-audience-targeting-through-object-model-moss-sharepoint-2007.aspx) it should be like this

```
public Class1(SPListItem item)
{
     string ID = item[FieldId.AudienceTargeting] as string;
     string NewID = ID.Remove(36);
     Guid guid = new Guid(NewID);
     Audience siteAudience = audManager.GetAudience(guid);
}
```

And then probably siteAudience.GetMembership();

Comment: what in the world is 36?  this does not look like a flexible solution to me

Answer (score 0):

That is useful when you want the first Audience. With those lines I'm inspired to do something like this, which should get me an array with all the audiences:

```
public Class1(SPListItem item)
{
    string ID = item[FieldId.AudienceTargeting] as string;
    string audiences = audienceTargeting.Split(';')[0];
    String[] audiencesArray = audiences.split(',');
```

}

And then iterate to get the audiences by the guid.

Keeping in mind the sintax of the audience target as it is described here: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2011/01/setting-target-audiences-with-code.html

I'll confirm later after testing.